# Calculate height and with of a group in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need the width and height of a group, in other words I need the maximum width and height taking all the elements in the group, for example this code should print 400/280, but instead prints null/null. Is this something that needs to be calculated manually?

```
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 500);
        var g = svg.append('g');

        g.append('rect').attr('type',1)                                         
                        .attr("width", 400)
                        .attr("height", 200);

        g.append('rect').attr('type',3)
                        .attr("width", 300)
                        .attr("height", 280);

        console.log(g.attr('width'));
        console.log(g.attr('height'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the width and height simply use this:

```
g.node().getBBox();
```

Working snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);
var g = svg.append('g');

g.append('rect').attr('type',1)                                         
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .attr('fill', 'red');

g.append('rect').attr('type',3)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 280);

console.log(g.node().getBBox());
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js"></script>
</body>
```

this will return:

> ```
> {
>   "x": 0,
>   "y": 0,
>   "width": 400,
>   "height": 280
> }
> ```

Comment: The height should be 280 and the width 400, not 5 and 5.

Comment: I'm giving example of output here, sorry for this I will update it

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing 'rect' while printing

```
g.append('rect').attr('type',3)

console.log(g.attr('width'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that may go wrong with `getElementById()` function. First, ensure the  tag is BELOW body, and not in it, because that would confuse everything. Even if you decide to link it, using the SRC property of a  tag, you should place it at the bottom. Also, just declare the object, but NOT the properties you are looking for, as you grab the properties at the bottom.

Hope this helps!

-Veggie